# Create bar graph wider

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I created a bar graph using `pgfplot` and option `ybar`. I would get a graph wider. I used `width option`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[ybar,
                             ymajorgrids=true,
                             xlabel=packet loss,ylabel=energia,
                             legend pos = north west]
            \addplot [fill=red!50,draw=red!50!black]
                table [x=pep,y=1]
                {./MATLAB/grafici/energia/broadcast_scenario/energy_broadcast_varpktslossprobability_100nodes.txt};
            \addplot [fill=blue!70, draw=blue!50!black]
                table [x=pep,y=20]
                {./MATLAB/grafici/energia/broadcast_scenario/energy_broadcast_varpktslossprobability_100nodes.txt};
            \addplot [fill=violet!70, draw=violet!50!black]
                table [x=pep,y=50]
                {./MATLAB/grafici/energia/broadcast_scenario/energy_broadcast_varpktslossprobability_100nodes.txt};
            \addplot [fill=orange!50, draw=orange!50!black]
                table [x=pep,y=100]
                {./MATLAB/grafici/energia/broadcast_scenario/energy_broadcast_varpktslossprobability_100nodes.txt};
            \legend{\footnotesize{$1$},\footnotesize{$20$},\footnotesize{$50$},\footnotesize{$100$}}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

but the plot became bigger in height and width. Instead I would have only a wider graph

Comment: I don't remember how many times I've already asked you to make [minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the needed packages.

Comment: I don't understand in this case which is the reason I have to put package...the example is not exacutable because it calls file in my hard disk. I'm asking only if it exist a option to get wider plot

Comment: People expert in plots usually have data files available. But you're not helping them in making a complete example that one can play with, without the need to guess packages.

Comment: ok right...I will add needed packages

Comment: are you looking for the `bar width` option?

Comment: bar width works for dimension of the bars instead I would have a plot wider in the sense bigger horizontally

Comment: If you give a width option and leave the height option free, it will try to keep the aspect ratio constant. Otherwise `x post scale` would be suitable for you though I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.